# snap carousel in npm for jackpot game using Angular?

Tags: angular

I am into a gaming project using Angular where i need a carousel with npm similar to the one in link below where user profile images are shuffled and randomly a user is selected as winner.

https://csgoatse.com/

Suggest me if any.